# How can I export my voice commands in Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 when the microphone configured for the profile isn't plugged in?

Tags: windows, dragon-naturally-speaking, speech-recognition, voice-command

How can I export my voice commands in Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 when the microphone configured for the profile isn't plugged in?

The "Open Vocabulary Editor" menu is a greyed out when the microphone configured for the profile isn't plugged in:

[image]

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 Professional with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to %programdata%\Nuance\NaturallySpeaking1X\users\YourUser\current and copy the MyCmds.dat file. It contains all your commands.

You can import it into another profile through the MyCommands Editor.

---

BTW, the Vocabulary Editor is not where the commands are, as it is in your screenshot, but in the MyCommands Editor. That would be under "Tools".

Comment: Thanks! It's even more convenient than exporting through the graphical user interface, which forces the user to select each context program one by one when exporting voice commands.